# use Javascript when jQuery is already declared?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how to use javascript when jquery has already been declared in the head. Javascript, in my opinion, is better to use for specific tasks, and jQuery is also better to use for some tasks. I am using jQuery, and jQuery UI, but it doesn't really matter what version I am using.

I have some simple jQuery here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
```

and I have some javascript right here:

```
document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(
      document.getElementById('C')
   );
```

I don't want to have the jQuery translated to js, or visa versa.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. So just continue using javascript

Comment: Your code is fine, however, you should choose a path.  If you are going to use jQuery, you might as well code the whole file using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is a library of javascript, but I don't want it translated drop js to jQuery or visa versa.

Comment: ya, but can I combine js with jQuery all in one script tag?

Comment: Yup, they're the same. jQuery is a library, you don't have to use it. If you want the javascript version of a jQuery selection, access the array: `$("button")[0]`

Comment: I am asking if I can use jQuery and javascript in the same script tag, not how I can use jQuery if I want, or if jQuery is javascript.

Comment: why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can combine both jquery and javascript in the same script tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var something = document.getElementById('productId');//javascript
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});//jquery.
    });
});
```

Javascript vs Jquery

> JavaScript is a language. jQuery is a library built with JavaScript to
>   help JavaScript programmers who are doing common web tasks. Which is
>   the best between JavaScript or JQuery is a contentious discussion, really the
>   answer is neither is best. They both have their roles.For some
>   application what is needed is straight JavaScript development. But for most
>   websites JQuery is all that is needed. What a web developer needs to
>   do is make an informed decision on what tools are best for their
>   client. Someone first coming into web development does need some
>   exposure to both technologies just using JQuery all the time does not
>   teach the nuances of JavaScript and how it affects the DOM. Using
>   JavaScript all the time slows projects down and because the JQuery
>   framework has ironed most of the issues that JavaScript will have
>   between each web browser it makes the deployment safe as it is sure to
>   work across all platforms.
>   Author: Tusar Gupta

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a library, Javascript is a language. jQuery is built using javascript, your language will not be changed by including jQuery. It just exposes pre-built functions for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the jQuery after all the javascript, like this:

```
    <script>
    document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(
          document.getElementById('C')
       );
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
    });
});
</script>
```

I know this should work.